# Getting the total size of rows with same ids across multiple tables restricted to a particular user id

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to calculate all the projects size of one user across multiple tables.

a unique project is separated into 4 tables with multiple rows assigned to it.

for the moment I'm only able to calculate one, here is what I have so far:

```
select  pg_size_pretty((
  select COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(s)), 0) as ts
  from editor_s s
  where project_uid = 'z_5oyUFV6615Lh1d-FabX' )
  +
  ( select COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(o)), 0) as os
  from editor_o o
  where project_uid = 'z_5oyUFV6615Lh1d-FabX' )
  +
  ( select COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(e)), 0) as es
  from editor_c e
  where project_uid = 'z_5oyUFV6615Lh1d-FabX' )
  +
  ( select COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(ss)), 0) as sss
  from editor_ss ss
  where project_uid = 'z_5oyUFV6615Lh1d-FabX' ))

as total
```

So let's say I want all projects sizes of user 3 I would like to receive back

```
|-------------------|
|project_uid|size   |
|-------------------|
| 1234ua    | 20kb  |
|-------------------|
| ze64ua    | 120kb |
|-------------------|
| bv76y1    | 93kb  |
|-------------------|
```

is this possible?

**EDIT**

As it would take a huge amount of time to reproduce the issue and create examples and as we are close to the point I'll try describe a bit more my attempt:

So one project has its data separated into 4 tables each project can have one or many rows refering to it's project_uid in a table.

1. `table1` have composite primary key `user_uid` and `project_uid` ( 1 row per project )
2. `table2` have composite primary key `uid`, `user_uid` and `project_uid`( multiple rows per project )
3. `table3` have composite primary key `uid`, `user_uid` and `project_uid`
4. `table4` have composite primary key `uid`, `user_uid` and `project_uid`

`uid` and `project_uid` are of type `TEXT` where `user_uid` is of type `UUID`

all tables have different numbers of columns with different data types (TEXT, JSONB, FLOAT...)

So what I would like is **get all the projects total sizes ( across all 4 tables ) grouped by project_uid and where user_uid = `'SOME_USER_UID'`**

so in pseudo code this would look something like ( and im sorry but I'm a newby in SQL databases so I'll write it as clear as I can )

PSEUDO CODE:

```
SELECT SUMS(
  SELECT ( 

    sum(pg_column_size(table1)),

    sum(pg_column_size(table2)),

    sum(pg_column_size(table3)),

    sum(pg_column_size(table4))

  ) GROUP BY project_uid ) WHERE user_uid = 'SOME USER UID';
```

ps: I've invented the operator `SUMS` for this example that would return multiple sums (rows)

Comment: Please create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14 with some sample data, and update your post with the url and expected result. You are probbaly looking for `GROUP BY` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make it work by doing:

```
select project_uid, sum(col_size) FROM (
  (select COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(s)), 0) as col_size, project_uid
  from editor_s s
  where user_uid = 'some_user_uid'
  group by project_uid )
  UNION ALL
  ( select COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(o)), 0) as col_size, project_uid
  from editor_o o
  where user_uid = 'some_user_uid'
  group by project_uid )
  UNION ALL
  ( select COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(e)), 0) as col_size, project_uid
  from editor_c e
  where user_uid = 'some_user_uid'
  group by project_uid )
  UNION ALL
  ( select COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(ss)), 0) as col_size, project_uid
  from editor_ss ss
  where user_uid = 'some_user_uid'
  group by project_uid )
) 
 as total group by project_uid;
```

Thank you to [@Lennart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39278/lennart)

Answer (score 1):

Some guessing:

```
SELECT project_uid, sum(col_size) 
FROM (
    SELECT project_uid, COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(s)), 0) as col_size
    FROM editor_s s
    GROUP BY project_uid

    UNION ALL

    SELECT project_uid, COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size(o)), 0) as col_size
    FROM editor_o o
    GROUP BY project_uid

    UNION ALL

    ...

) AS t
GROUP BY project_uid
```

Comment: Just saw your answer, thanks a lot but there are errors columns are not of the same size. I'll do what you ask and provide an example. THank again for your time.

Comment: I've added an edit to my post. Sorry but creating an example would take a huge amount of time and I would need to obfuscate my data. So I've tried to explain as precisely as possible. Please tell me if you need more infos. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I'm afraid it will take me even longer to create an working example. You can try to add a WHERE user_uid = 'SOME USER UID' to each leg in the UNION sub-select

Comment: too bad, the thing is that as mentionned before, because of different number of collumns the `union all` is not working any alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create "dummy" columns to make the legs union compatible, but without an example it's difficult to be more specific than that

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: I've written an answer. Thank you very much you really helped.Can you correct your answer?

Comment: You can mark your own solution as the correct one, you just have to wait  for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Thanks you very much Lennart